# Yellow text on startup - Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have an ubuntu 20.04 server and when I start my server the text is yellow? I have searched google but I haven't found anyone with the same problem as me, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless this happens to only occur in combination with rare configurations only relevant to managing systems in a business environment, this question may be more appropriate on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Only partly joke, because I had this exact problem before and it really was the cable: Have you tried unplugging and reinserting the VGA connector?

Comment: @anx sadly, this didnt work

Comment: @anx the text is displayed on the login screen dmesg: https://pastebin.com/KHkQn9ku